# How to add additional variables to an existing template config in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-8

I have one theme config in one module.

```
/**
* Implements hook_theme().
*/
function module1_context_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
 return [
  'custom_theme' => [
    'template' => 'custom_theme',
    'variables' => [
      'var1' => NULL,
      'var2' => NULL,
    ],
   ],
 ];
}
```

I want to add an extra variable to the theme config via other module.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **HOOK_theme_registry_alter** to alter this. Try the below code.

```
/**
* Implements hook_theme_registry_alter
*/
function my_module_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['custom_theme']['variables'][] = 'var3';
}
```